# Removing duplicates from dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program i am making is to validate a sudoku from a text file. So far i have this.

```
file=input("Enter a filename: ")
with open(file) as data:
    rowt=[0 for i in range(9)]
    colt=[0 for i in range(9)]
    for a,b in enumerate(data):
        sb_rowt = 0
        print (a,b)
        for c, d in enumerate(b.split()):
            print (c,d)
            sb_rowt+=int(d)
            colt[c]+=int(d)
        rowt[a]=sb_rowt
    rows=all(i==45 for i in rowt)
    cols=all(i==45 for i in colt)
    print(rows and cols)
```

The problem with this is that if i have a text file such as this

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

the program will still output as true. i know i need to remove any duplicate entries but i am unsure of how.

Comment: Instead of checking whether the sum adds up to 45, just check whether all the numbers are present!

Answer (score 0):

By you question, I think you are not on the right track. Whether valid or not, there should always be 9*9 numbers on the board. You get the right input, but fail to validate it. **Think about refining you validation algorithm**.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the reading and validation operations:

```
# read first
file = input("Enter a filename: ")
with open(file) as data:
    array = [ [ int(i) for i in line.split() ] for line in data ]
```

And validate only then.

```
# first create a set of numbers 1...9
all_numbers = set(range(1, 10))

# validate rows and columns:
valid = True

# we validate ith row and column in the same loop
for i in range(9):
    row_i    = array[i]
    column_i = [ array[rownum][i] for rownum in range(9) ]
    valid   &= set(row_i) == all_numbers
    valid   &= set(column_i) == all_numbers

# valid is True if all constraints succeeded.

# TODO: in sudoku you also need to validate the 
# 3x3 subsquares.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not just use the *sum* of the numbers to validate the grid. Instead, you have to check whether each row and each column contains all the numbers from 1 to 9.

You could try something like this:

```
all_nums = set(range(1, 10))
with open("data") as data:
    field = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in data]
    rows = map(set, field)
    cols = map(set, zip(*field))
    rows_ok = all(row == all_nums) for row in rows)
    cols_ok = all(col == all_nums) for col in cols)
```

First, I create a list of lists of integers from the data input. Then I extract the rows and columns (`zip(*field)` basically flips `field` on the side) and turn those into `set`s, since order is not important. Finally, I just compare `all` the rows and columns to the set of `all_nums`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import collections

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    board = [[int(i) for i in row] for row in csv.reader(infile)]
for r,row in enumerate(board):
    counts = collections.Counter(row)
    if all(row[k]==1 for k in range(1,10)):
        continue
    raise ValueError("failed on row %d" %r)

for c,col in enumerate(zip(*rows)):
    if all(col[k]==1 for k in range(1,10)):
        continue
    raise ValueError("failed on col %d" %c)

# todo: check each 3x3 square
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply your board as list of lists:

```
def validate(board):
    valid = set(range(1, 10))
    return (all(valid == set(r) for r in board) and
            all(valid == set(c) for c in zip(*board)) and
            all(valid == set(board[i][j:j+3] + board[i+1][j:j+3] + board[i+2][j:j+3])
                for i in (0, 3, 6) for j in (0, 3, 6)))
```